# getting OHLCV data for multiple stocks with getSymbols.av function from quantmod R package from alpha vantage

Tags: r, alpha-vantage

Could you please anybody give a working example for the getting OHLCV data for multiple stocks with getSymbols.av function from quantmod R package from alpha vantage?
This is what I've tried for example:

```
getSymbols.av(c("JYNT","APPS"),env = en,src="av", api.key=myapi, output.size="full")
```

but I did not get the data.

Comment: Looks like you have to make calls for each new symbol in that package. You'd have to write a small for-loop to do it.

Comment: thanks! Then it means basically the maximum number of the calls in 500 per day - and seems there is no way to increase it

Comment: Correct. To maintain performance for all standard key users, the max number of calls a day is 500. Premium key holders have unlimited.